# Data factory: Inserting the body in a copy data activity source

Tags: api, rest, azure-data-factory, pipeline

I am trying to get data from a REST API. According to the documentation, the API needs to have a date in the body like this:

```
{"date": "2023-01-05"}
```

It's working when I try it in Postman. When I try it in Azure Data Factory, it doesn't work.
I have a copy of data activity, the source is a Linked service REST API call. The necessary headers are inserted.

I have tried to insert the body in the additional headers, but that did not work.
My question is:
How/where can I insert the body of in the source of a copy data activity when the source is a REST API Linked service?

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoEfd.png) of the source in the copy activity and the error code I am getting

Error code:

> Rest call failed with client error, status code 422 422, please check
> your activity settings. Request URL:
> https://api.gastroplanner.eu/booking/v1/bookings. Response:
> {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"date":["The date
> field is required when year month is not present."]}}

Comment: You have given `@item()` in your headers. that means you are running the copy activity inside a loop. Can you provide the value of it? and also can you provide a sample data from your REST API?

Comment: If you need to pass data on body, use HTTP POST instead of GET

Answer (score 0):

Here, I tried to give the **request body** using Json directly while using `GET` request and it took it successfully as you see in below image. But when I tried to validate or publish it gave me error as below:

> **REST connector doesn't support GET requests with request body.**

[image]

So, AFAIK to pass the request body you need to use post request.

You can raise the feature request for this feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).